# Cannot setup tern_for_vim plugin

Tags: linux-ubuntu, plugin-ternjs

I installed the plugin [tern_for_vim](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim). Followed all the instructions from readme but it doesn't work. I don't have any autocompletion for javascript, the commands `:TernDef` and `:TernDoc` are not recognized in vim. I installed the tern server globally using `npm` and I can launch it.

I tried to launch tern with the `--verbose` option but it did not output anything when I tried to use autocompletion in javascript files. It seems that there is no communication between vim and the tern server if I understand it correctly.

Here are my plugins in `.vimrc` file:

```
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'mxw/vim-jsx'
Plugin 'alvan/vim-closetag'
Plugin 'Valloric/MatchTagAlways'
Plugin 'ternjs/tern_for_vim'
Plugin 'lervag/vimtex'
```

I also setup a `.tern-config` file in the home directory:

```
{
    "libs": [
    "ecmascript",
    "browser",
    "jquery"
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "es_modules": {},
    "node": {}
    }
}
```

I could run ternjs when I set up YouCompleteMe for python autocompletion, but I didn't like it and chose jedi-vim (which is really nice). Now I want to setup javascript autocompletion but without no luck.

Any suggestions how I can solve this problem?

Comment: As I often advise on plugin specific questions like this: You should see for help on the [plugin's issue tracker](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/issues): you'll find people who develop/maintain the plugin and use it on a regular basis and who should be able to help you.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` in the `tern_for_vim` directory? Furthermore, Tern commands are available only in `javascript` files.

Comment: @LEI, Yes I did run npm install inside of the tern_for_vim directory. Before that I installed tern globally as was suggested on issues page of github for this plugin.

Comment: Try to open a JS file and look for "tern_for_vim" or more specifically `<plugin_dir>/tern_for_vim/after/ftplugin/javascript_tern.vim` in the `:scriptnames` output. If you can't find it, the plugin is probably not loaded at all and you should debug your vimrc.

Comment: @LEI, I can see `javascript_tern.vim` and `../autoload/tern.vim` in the output of `:scriptnames`. What can I do?

Comment: @Nurzhan `:set filetype?` should be set to `javascript`. Try to manually execute `:call tern#Enable()`.

Comment: @LEI, I enabled tern manually as you suggested and the commands TernDef, TernDoc appeared. But I still don't see any autocompletion. Is it possible that the plugin tern_for_vim is in conflict with some of my other plugins?

Comment: @LEI, what is the default shortcut for autocompletion for javascript in tern_for_vim?

Comment: @Nurzhan As said in [the issue you created](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/issues/175), `<C-x><C-o>` can be used to trigger omnicompletion. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64412/discussion-between-lei-and-nurzhan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are editing a JS file (`echo &filetype` should output `javascript`), and check the function used for omni completion:

```
:verbose setlocal omnifunc?
```

It should display something like:

```
  omnifunc=tern#Complete
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/tern_for_vim/autoload/tern.vim
```

If not the case, then `tern_for_vim/after/ftplugin/javascript_tern.vim` may not be loaded (`:scriptnames`). This file contains the call to `tern#Enable()` which in turn sets the local `&omnifunc` to `tern#Complete` .

To manually enable omni completion (as a quickfix), you could try:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal omnifunc=tern#Complete
```

Then start completion in insert mode with `<C-x><C-o>`.

- `:h compl-omni`
- `:h 'omnifunc'`